# When visiting the cemetery do we say משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם in the blessing of אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין?

Tags: blessing, cemetery-grave, geshem-tal-ruach

When visiting the cemetery after a break of 30 days, it is [customary to say Nusach Ashkenaz](https://www.wikiwand.com/he/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F)

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם
> בַּדִּין וְזָן וְכִלְכֵּל אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין, וְהֵמִית אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין,
> וְיוֹדֵעַ מִסְפַּר כֻּלְּכֶם בַּדִּין, וְהוּא עָתִיד לְהַחֲיוֹתְכֶם
> וּלְקַיֵּם אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין,
>
> אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם אֲדֹנָי  מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב
> לְהוֹשִׁיעַ    מְכַלְכֵּל חַיִּים בְּחֶסֶד.
> מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים בְּרַחֲמִים רַבִּים. סוֹמֵךְ נוֹפְלִים וְרוֹפֵא
> חוֹלִים וּמַתִּיר אֲסוּרִים. וּמְקַיֵּם אֱמוּנָתוֹ לִישֵׁנֵי עָפָר.
> מִי כָמוֹךָ בַּעַל גְּבוּרוֹת וּמִי דוֹמֶה לָךְ. מֶלֶךְ מֵמִית
> וּמְחַיֶּה וּמַצְמִיחַ יְשׁוּעָה.  וְנֶאֱמָן אַתָּה לְהַחֲיוֹת מֵתִים

In the regular Amidah, it would be customary to say at the appropriate time of the year

> משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם

after

> אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם אֲדֹנָי מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב
> לְהוֹשִׁיעַ

Is that the case when visiting the cemetery?

Comment: Also מי כמכה אב הרחמים

Comment: You say "it is customary to say [these two paragraphs]" but really the first paragraph is obligatory while only the second one is indeed wholly customary (and as such need not match any existing halachot or customs of anything else).

Comment: @Heshy Not כמוך?

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't give it too much thought

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi [Yechiel Michel Tucazinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Tucazinsky) (יחיאל מיכל טוקצינסקי) in [גשר החיים part II, 27:6](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31172&pgnum=215) (באמירת אתה גבור אחר ברכת ראיית קברים) says:

> מה ששמע שיש מנהג לומר באתה גבור אחר הברכה שבבית הקברות "מוריד הטל" גם בחורף — הנה גם אני שמעתי שיש נוהגים כך, ולא שיש מנהג כזה אלא שיש מהדרין בכך כדי להזכיר הטל של תחי' (בשגם כשאומרים מוריד הטל אף בחורף בדיעבד יצא). אולם אני לא הזכרתי זאת משום שאין אני קובע בזה שום מסמר, דבכלל אמירת אתה גבור, הגם שבפרק כ"ט (י"ז) הבאתי מהמנהג להוסיף אתה גבור ונדפס כך בסדור דה"ח ועוד — אין לזה מקור ולא הובא בפוסקים, מכש"כ אמירת מוריד הטל שלא נזכר בשום מקום והאומר בחורף משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם לא הפסיד

In my translation:

> [Regarding] what you heard that there is a custom to say in אתה גבור, [that is said] after the blessing [said] at the cemetery, "מוריד הטל" in the winter also — I also heard that there are those who do so, and not because there is a[n established] custom in the matter, but [rather] that they make a point of doing it so as to mention the dew that will revive the dead (as even if one says מוריד הטל [in the *Amidah*] in the winter, they've nevertheless fulfilled their obligation [and don't need to repeat the blessing; [SA OC 114:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.114.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]). I did not mention this [in part I of the book] because I do not [wish to] make any definite statements in the matter, as in general the saying of אתה גבור, though in [[part I] chapter 29 (section 17)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&pgnum=277) I brought the custom of saying אתה גבור as it is printed in the דרך החיים (?) prayer book and elsewhere — it has no source and was not brought in the *Halakhic* rulings, furthermore saying מוריד הטל [in אתה גבור said at the cemetery] is not mentioned anywhere, so one who says in the winter משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם does not lose [the proper saying of that blessing].

In short, he says:

- Saying מוריד הטל in the winter (instead of משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם) in the אתה גבור section said in the cemetery (after the אשר יצר אתכם בדין blessing) is not an established custom.
- Those who do so do it to mention/hint at the טל של תחייה (the dew that will revive the dead; [Shabbat 88b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.88b.6?lang=bi&lang2=en)).
- As saying אתה גבור in the cemetery has no source, and is not mentioned in the *Halakhic* rulings, and saying מוריד הטל in it in the winter is not mentioned anywhere, one may say משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely since the following siddurim do not have the text of משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם after
אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם אֲדֹנָי מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב לְהוֹשִׁיעַ recited in the cemetery:

[Avodas Yisroel, Baer, p586](https://he.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93:Seligman_Baer_-_Seder_Avodat_Yisroel_(1901_ed.).pdf/607&action=edit&redlink=1),

[Authorised Daily Prayer Book, p320](https://opensiddur.org/compilations/liturgical/siddurim/kol-bo/the-authorised-daily-prayer-book-aka-the-singer-siddur/)

and [Artscroll Siddur, p796](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066509.html)