# Why do we not say משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם after אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם אֲדֹנָי מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב לְהוֹשִׁיעַ recited in the cemetery?

Tags: cemetery-grave, geshem-tal-ruach

I asked the question [When visiting the cemetery do we say משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם in the blessing of אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126894/when-visiting-the-cemetery-do-we-say-%d7%9e%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%91-%d7%94%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%97-%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%93-%d7%94%d7%92%d7%a9%d7%9d-in-the-blessing-of-%d7%90%d6%b2/126900#126900)

and later answered it:

> we do not say  משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם after אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם
> אֲדֹנָי מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב לְהוֹשִׁיעַ recited in the
> cemetery.

The next question is why don't we say it. In the same passage in the Amidah we do say it and have to go back if we leave it out.

Why do we not say  משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם after אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם אֲדֹנָי מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב לְהוֹשִׁיעַ recited in the cemetery in the winter?

Comment: It isn't really relevant to visiting the cemetery. It is relevant to Shmoneh Esrei, so we put it in that bracha.

Answer (score 1):

In [Gemoro Berachos 33a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.33a.13?lang=bi&with=Chasidut&lang2=en) Chazal ask why גבורת גשמים - the power of Hashem to bring rain (which is משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם)    is mentioned in the blessing of the resurrection of the dead, and Rav Yosef answers that it similar to the resurrection of the dead (as rain revives new life in the plant world).

From this question in the Gemoro, we see that the prime thing is the resurrection of the dead and the ability to bring rain is compared  to it. At the cemetery the prayer understandably is concerned with resurrection; there is no need to add  the secondary ability to bring rain. The scope of the Amidah is much greater  than the prayer in the cemetery and it is appropriate to include  משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם.